# Breakpoint on api exposed from COM interface

Tags: com, windbg, breakpoints

Lets say thers is one interface

```
interface Ifoo
{
   HRESULT foo();
};
```

which is part of a binary dll.  I dont have source code for this.

Can I put a breakpoint on foo() API   exposed from the interface Ifoo of this binary dll using Windbg?

I know we can put breakpoints on binary dll's using windbg but using COM I am not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well thanks for pointing out, I actually meant putting breakpoint on implementation of foo.

So I found out. In my case I wanted to put breakpoint on one of windows system dll.

So I ran commands on Windbg as

```
> x  dllname*!foo*
```

It gave me list of foo implementations in in dlls with name matching dllname.

like

```
7331122 dllname!CFoo::foo
```

Then with using this address I put breakpoints

```
bp 7331122
```

U can view the set breakpoints using command

```
 >bl
```

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of whether you use COM or not, you cannot put breakpoints on an interface: An interface is never executed, so there is no way to "break" on an interface.

If, however, you know that Ifoo is implemented by CFoo, you could, of course, set a breakpoint on CFoo::foo.